PHP artisan db:seed command
I'm working on my Laravel project and I keep encountering an issue. I've tried using fake()->unique(true), but the problem persists. I need to resolve this by Monday. Here is the error I'm encountering:

INFO  Seeding database.
Illuminate\Database\UniqueConstraintViolationException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "email_verified_at", "role", "password", "remember_token", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Test User, test@example.com, 2024-04-12 10:51:32, 5, $2y$12$rSTlxEdNiX8ShdSLLeteO.fFTWzAyl/cRv0AX9kojtZi96R6pxSi.,
Sh8wyhWs8u, 2024-04-12 10:51:32, 2024-04-12 10:51:32))
at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:808
804▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
805▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
806▕         catch (Exception $e) {
807▕             if ($this->isUniqueConstraintError($e)) {
➜ 808▕                 throw new UniqueConstraintViolationException(
809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
810▕                 );
811▕             }
812▕
1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email")mail")
2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
PDOStatement::execute()


You're trying to insert a user with email test@example.com, this email address already exists. This address seems to be hard-coded and originates from somewhere other than your factory

How can I remove it

Without code, that's impossible for us to tell

I found it thank you for your help really appreciate it
